# How to delete a file named -something with rm

Tags: command-line, sudo, rm

When I have a file named `-19-5-20674.`, how can I delete that file?

When I use `sudo rm`:

```
$ sudo rm -19-5-20674.
rm: invalid option -- '1'
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

have a try with`sudo rm ./-19-5-20674.` or with `sudo rm -- -19-5-20674.`

your sudo reads the filename due to it's leading dash as an optional parameter / command option. most shells understand a double dash to signal end of command options.  i circumvent this with a relative path as shown.